# How to center, have an active tab, and also have the tabs take larger screen width for Bootstrap tabs?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, tabs, center, styling

I'm currently running into a bootstrap issue where I'm trying to make my bootstrap tabs do 3 things.

1. Center the Tabs in the center of the page.
2. Have the content of my Team immedieatly display.
3. Have the tabs and the table content take a majority of the screen.

**Here are images of my issue:**

Before clicking on Team
[image]

After Clicking on Team
[image]

Currently, here is my tabs code:

```
<div class="container tab-bar d-flex justify-content-center ">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-pressed="true">
        Team</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="true">Individual</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab1-tab">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row p-2">
                   <%= render :partial => "teams_list", locals: {teams: @teams} %>
              
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab2-tab">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-2">
        <%= render :partial => "users/users_list", locals: {teams: @teams} %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

_teams_list.html.erb

```
<% if @teams.empty? %>
  <h4>There are no teams in the system at this time.</h4>
<% else %>

  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th scope="col">Team Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @teams.each do |team| %>
        <tr>
          <td>Rank</td>
          <td><%= team.name %></td>
          <td><%= team.total_points %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  <%= link_to 'New Team', new_team_path %>

<%end%>
```

users/users_list.html.erb

```
<% if @users.nil? %>
  <h4>There are no users in the system at this time.</h4>
<% else %>

  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th scope="col">Team Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Points</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <tr>
          <td>Rank</td>
          <td><%= user.name %></td>
          <td><%= user.points %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  <%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>

<%end%>
```

Comment: Can you show your partial view codes? i.e., "teams_list" and "users/users_list"?

Comment: edited the post to add it!

Comment: Even though you're not supposed to have nested containers, I cannot reproduce the issue you have: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/0p8w9v4s/20/

Comment: What do you mean by nested container?

Comment: The most outter is a container `<div class="container tab-bar" />`, and then you have 2 containers nested within under tab panes. It's just a good practice to have a single container as the outer and rows, columns inside. It's not recommended to have another container inside a container.

Answer (score 0):

Add "d-flex" class to container, just before justify-content

```
<div class="container tab-bar d-flex justify-content-center">
```

You can force the active appearance with .active (and include the aria-pressed="true" attribute) should you need to replicate the state programmatically. Also, I removed "aria-selected", you can read why here: https://www.stefanjudis.com/blog/aria-selected-and-when-to-use-it/.

```
      <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-pressed="true">
        Team</a>
```

Added example of code together:

```
        <div class="container tab-bar d-flex justify-content-center">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="tab1-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" role="tab" aria-controls="tab1" aria-pressed="true">
                  Team</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="tab2-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2" role="tab" aria-controls="tab2" aria-selected="true">Individual</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hmm the d-flex part actually moved the content to the side, as if everything is in-line block. Also, thee active part hasn't worked for me :/

Comment: I edited my comment to combine the code that works for me, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm still having everything display as in-line block and the active isn't working either. I've updated my code to reflect your changes.

Comment: Oh removing the d-flex has helped me center everything. However, I still can't seem to force the "active" yet